# My mouse stops moving the pointer after a few minutes of inactivity

Tags: windows-xp, mouse

I'm using a Gigaware wireless optical mouse on Windows XP. After the mouse is inactive for about five minutes — keyboard activity doesn't matter — moving the mouse doesn't move the mouse pointer. Only after I click or right-click a button will the mouse "wake up" and start moving the pointer.

I checked the properties of the mouse in Device Manager, and the Mouse menu in Control Panel, but didn't see anything that could be responsible.

How can I make my mouse stay "awake" all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a "feature" of the wireless mouse itself.

I have a wireless laptop mouse that does the same thing - it puts itself to sleep to save battery power, and it requires a click to wake it up.

Comment: It's probably a feature on the hardware side directly, indeed. I doubt this firm made software to change that.

Answer (score 4):

Some ideas:

Check Device Manager / Mouse Properties / Details / Power State Mappings, to see if it's similar to this:

[image]

Then try to find in the software that came with your mouse if there is any reference to a Power-save mode that can be disabled.

If not, try to find a newer version of the driver on the manufacturer's site, that will maybe have a way to disable Power-save.

And lastly, as there are so many bad [reviews](http://butterfliesandbugaboosnielsenfamily.blogspot.com/2008/02/gigaware-wireless-optical-mouse.html) for this mouse, buy another one.

Comment: for mice i have "HID-compliant mouse", there's a Power Management tab, and it has two items: "Allow Computer to turn off this device to save power" - this option is NOT checked and is disabled (i'm logged in as admin). and "Allow this device to bring the computer out of standby" -- this option is enabled and IS checked.

Comment: The settings in Power Management are correct. The problem is with the mouse driver. "HID-compliant mouse" is a fancy name for a USB mouse. I believe your driver is Microsoft-generic, but you can check the publisher in its properties in Device Manager. It might even be that this mouse has no specific driver and relies on Microsoft.